# When does there exist a section of $GL_n(\mathbb Z_p) \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb F_p)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is a reduction map $f: GL_n(\mathbb Z_p) \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb F_p)$  for any prime $p$, when does there exist a group homomorphism $g: GL_n(\mathbb F_p) \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$ such that $f\circ g=id$?

If $n=1$ this is always possible, and if $p-1>n$ this is always impossible as $\mathbb F_p \not \subseteq GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$ by considering the minimal polynomial.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}_p$? As in arbitrary field of order $p^k$?

Comment: @freakish it normally means the field of order $p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Hmm, then how is it different from $\mathbb{Z}_p$? Isn't $f$ simply the identity in this case? I'm confused.

Comment: @freakish here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means the $p$-adics

Comment: @freakish As the pedant in me would like to suggest that it always should, since there are a pile of perfectly serviceable notations for $\Bbb{F}_p$ or $\Bbb{Z}/p$ or $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$ that don't conflict with the standard notation for the $p$-adics, $\Bbb{Z}_p$. I die a little inside every time someone on this site uses $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to denote the integers mod $p$.

Comment: At the end of your post you meant if $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is of order $p$ then its minimal polynomial divides $\frac{X^p-1}{X-1}\in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ but the latter is irreducible so $n \ge p-1$. And since $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1}\in GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is of order $p$ there is no embedding $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)\to GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ for $n < p-1$

Comment: Your argument that $\mathbb{F}_p$ cannot occur as a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ if $n<p-1$ can be generalized. For an arbitrary positive integer $k$, if $n\geq p^{k-1}+1$, then there is an element of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ of order $p^k$ (take a unipotent matrix with $1$-dimensional eigenspace, or a power of this matrix). In order for there to be an element of order $p^k$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, we need $n\geq \varphi(p^k)$. So no section can exist if $p^{k-1}+1\leq n\leq p^{k-1}(p-1)-1$.

Comment: So with $A_m(i,j) = 1_{j=i+m}$ then $A_m A_{m'} = A_{m+m'}$ and $(I+A_1)^{p^k}= \sum_{m=0}^{p^k} {p^k \choose m} A_1^m=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} {p^k \choose m} A_m$ which is $=I$ iff $p\ |\ {p^k \choose  p^k-(n-1)}$ that is $n-1 < p^{k-1}$.

Comment: @jgon Slightly off-topic, but for notating something like the integers mod $n+1$ (if one needs the integers mod both $n$ and $n+1$), what notation would work best? All of the ones you've listed become more cumbersome when the modulus is more than one character.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut $\Bbb{Z}/(n+1)$ would be what I would use, and I don't think it's more cumbersome visually than $\Bbb{Z}_{n+1}$, and it's the same number of characters to type. Also I think it's less cumbersome visually than the subscript when the modulus becomes even more complex. After all, that's similar to why the $\exp(x)$ notation is so useful rather than $e^x$ when $x$ is a complicated expression.

Comment: @jgon: $\mathbb Z_p$ is well established as a notation for both the $p$-adics and for the integers modulo $p$. Best learn to live with it.

Answer (score 5):

Unless there are some small counterexamples (like maybe n=p=2?) that I don't want to account for, the answer is never.

$GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ can be embedded inside $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (as $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can be embedded as a ring in $\mathbb{C}$), but (away from a few small pairs (n,p)) the smallest nontrivial complex representation of $SL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has dimension $\frac{p^n - p}{p-1} > n$. See "Minimal characters of the finite classical groups" by Tiep and Zalesski for a chart of low dimensional characters.

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ being embedded in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ forces any subgroup of it to also be embedded, so this hypothetical representation of $SL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ would have to be faithful and thus definitely not trivial.